# How can I get console.log to output the getter result instead of the string "[Getter/Setter]"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, console, getter-setter

In this code:

```
function Cls() {
    this._id = 0;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        get: function() {
            return this._id;
        },
        set: function(id) {
            this._id = id;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
};
var obj = new Cls();
obj.id = 123;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.id);
```

I would like to get { _id: 123, id: 123 }
but instead I get { _id: 123, id: [Getter/Setter] }

Is there a way to have the getter value be used by the console.log function?

Comment: If you click on the output of `[getter]` in the console, it should be executed and evolve into the value.

Comment: @Bergi, it looks like the code is executed in node.js since its tagged, OP wouldnt be able to click on it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Ooops, of course. Not sure whether `util.inspect` would be of some help?

Comment: I know how to get to the value, what I don't know is how to design a class or library so it's transparent to the user of that lib. I don't want it to appear any other way then a clean value.

Comment: Would perhaps valueOf() of toString() be useful? I'd also like soem help on the browser side. I currently get three items, the getter, the setter, and a linked ... value that, when clicked returns the correct item. Needless to say, that really spams up my console output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my particular use-case I couldn't import the native inspect module, and I also couldn't do `JSON.stringify` on my logged object because there were circular references within it. But, I found that you can pass all of the [inspect options](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) as the second argument to `console.dir(obj, options)`. Thus, the following worked for me:

```js
console.dir(myObj, { getters: true });
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `console.log(Object.assign({}, obj));`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The Object.assign function calls getters internally and returns a POJO (with some caveats).
From [MDN: Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign): `"The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object. It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties, versus copying or defining new properties."`

Answer (score 9):

Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: that works except for methods and recursive refs, any suggestions for those objects?

Comment: I don't need to know how to print the value some other way. After all console.log(obj.id) does just that. I need to figure out how to have the console.log behave the same on a getter/setter property as on a primitive value.

Comment: There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution here but using JSON.stringify and adding a `toJSON` method to your objects seems like the best solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior -- You could also automate toJSON with some reflection and `Object.defineProperty( ... { value: })`

Answer (score 5):

Since Nodejs v11.5.0 you can set `getters: true` in the `util.inspect` options. [See here for docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

> getters <boolean> | <string> If set to true, getters are inspected. If set to 'get', only getters without a corresponding setter are inspected. If set to 'set', only getters with a corresponding setter are inspected. This might cause side effects depending on the getter function. Default: false.

Comment: Good info, thanks. But doesn't help with the original premise to stay compatible with the `console.*` api.

Comment: @Killroy configure `console.*` output in the [default inspect preferences](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_defaultoptions)

Answer (score 4):

You can define an `inspect` method on your object, and export the properties you are interested in. See docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects

I guess it would look something like:

```
function Cls() {
    this._id = 0;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        get: function() {
            return this._id;
        },
        set: function(id) {
            this._id = id;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
};

Cls.prototype.inspect = function(depth, options) {
    return `{ 'id': ${this._id} }`
}

var obj = new Cls();
obj.id = 123;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.id);
```

Comment: Does this work for console.log() ? The docs only mention utils.inspect. Ideally I am looking for something that's transparent to the user. If the user has to do something other then plain console.log(), they might as well just inspect the getter manually anyway.

Comment: Yeah, `console.log` calls `util.inspect`:        https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args

Answer (score 4):

I needed a pretty printed object without the getters and setters yet plain JSON produced garbage. For me as the JSON string was just too long after feeding `JSON.stringify()` a particularly big and nested object. I wanted it to look like and behave like a plain stringified object in the console. So I just parsed it again:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(largeObject))
```

There. If you have a simpler method, let me know.

Comment: Would this be similar (but less efficient) to `Object.assign({}, largeObject})` ?

Comment: This is the only one that works with a Vue object that has getters and setters also on the properties inside the object in arrays.  The accepted answer only works with the outer object not it's inner array.

Answer (score 1):

On Node.js, I suggest using [util.inspect.custom](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects), which will allow you to pretty print getters as values, while keeping other properties output unchanged.

It will apply to your specific object only and won't mess the general console.log output.

The main benefit vs `Object.assign` is that it happens on your object, so you keep the regular generic `console.log(object)` syntax. You don't have to wrap it with `console.log(Object.assign({}, object))`.

Add the following method to your object:

```js
[util.inspect.custom](depth, options) {
    const getters = Object.keys(this);
    /*
        for getters set on prototype, use instead:
        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        const getters = Object.keys(prototype);
    */
    const properties = getters.map((getter) => [getter, this[getter]]);
    const defined = properties.filter(([, value]) => value !== undefined);
    const plain = Object.fromEntries(defined);
    const object = Object.create(this, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(plain));
    // disable custom after the object has been processed once to avoid infinite looping
    Object.defineProperty(object, util.inspect.custom, {});
    return util.inspect(object, {
        ...options,
        depth: options.depth === null ? null : options.depth - 1,
    });
}
```

Here is a working example in your context:

```js
const util = require('util');

function Cls() {
    this._id = 0;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        get: function() {
            return this._id;
        },
        set: function(id) {
            this._id = id;
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
    this[util.inspect.custom] = function(depth, options) {
    const getters = Object.keys(this);
    /*
        for getters set on prototype, use instead:
        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        const getters = Object.keys(prototype);
    */
    const properties = getters.map((getter) => [getter, this[getter]]);
    const defined = properties.filter(([, value]) => value !== undefined);
    const plain = Object.fromEntries(defined);
    const object = Object.create(this, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(plain));
    // disable custom after the object has been processed once to avoid infinite looping
    Object.defineProperty(object, util.inspect.custom, {});
    return util.inspect(object, {
        ...options,
        depth: options.depth === null ? null : options.depth - 1,
    });
}
};
var obj = new Cls();
obj.id = 123;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.id);
```

Output:

```sh
Cls { _id: 123, id: 123 }
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator:

```
console.log({ ... obj });
```