# javascript make getters visible via console.log

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter

How to make `console.log()` display all getter properties? Right now, this prints `{}` with an arrow to open it :

[image]

I want it to be printed like this in the console : `{ foo: 1 }`.

```js
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function(){
    return 1
  }
});

console.log(obj) // this outputs empty object {}, i want it to output { foo: 1 }
```

Comment: Even if it is possible, it might be a bad idea to change `console.log()` to do that directly. Calling a getter might expect from the caller to do certain tasks with the returned/created value. So if you add such a functionality directly to the `console.log` then you might accitantialy break some program logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get console.log to output the getter result instead of the string "\[Getter/Setter\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072671/how-can-i-get-console-log-to-output-the-getter-result-instead-of-the-string-ge)

Comment: `console.log` is not standardized. Different browsers use different rules for printing an object. This seems like an unnecessary endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for seems to be `JSON.stringify()` which creates a string in the JSON format.

```js
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function() {
    return 1
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: can i do it without JSON.stringify() it?

Comment: If you only want to print the object itself, `console.log()` is the way to do it, but the output then depends on the console you are using. Chrome for example shows `{}` with a little arrow down on the left, which when clicked reveals all the other obvious, self defined and hidden properties like prototype and such